# Do we need a cache layer for cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, redis

I am playing/evaluating a realtime streaming application with millions of user activity logs, the design was to use Cassandra as a persistent store and use redis as a cache layer to store recent  activities (last 1000). I am looking for a suggestion whether such a cache layer necessary along with cassandra. Is cassandra capable to get best read and write performance?  The activities are streamed to front end as pages of 10 or 15 records. Suggestions are expected to use any alternative noSQL solutions as well

Comment: Depends on your use-case, hardware, read/write access patterns, etc. Share more information, and I'm sure you'll get some help ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends a lot on your requirements - Cassandra is reasonably fast for most common purposes, but redis will be faster, so having a caching layer is a reasonable and common approach. It's not strictly necessary, but it's not a bad idea.

Comment: Ty Jeff. I expected the same. Looking to achieve 1 million users and each user has 10 reads/sec with the Cassandra cluster. In other words, 10 million reads/sec... As i said redis store most recent 1000, i am facing a bit synchronization problem( i use my code to sync the cassandra and redis) for a fast moving stream in the real time particularly when something failed. I know that i could optimize my code to make it perfect, rather i am a fan of avoiding redis which reduce the maintenance .

Comment: You can do 10m reads/second in cassandra, but it's a non-trivial setup. Redis in front of it will make it MUCH easier, you'll just have to figure out the syncronization problem

Comment: I wish to accept your answer.  Can you enlighten the non-trivial set up?  any links or example would be fine

Comment: 10M reads/second is probably on the order of hundreds of cassandra hosts. The non-trivial part of it is that it's a VERY big cassandra cluster. In practice, it's probably multiple cassandra clusters (sharded).